# Duration of videoWriter being controlled with fps and frame Count (OpenCV & Python)

Tags: python, opencv, video-processing

When use the code below, it gives me a video from stream which has desired number of frames and FPS I choose. However, video length becomes  `duration =(1/fps)*frameCount`. I guess that mp4 does video compression so that the duration of the video does not make the file size bigger, this is a good thing. Nevertheless, is there a way to have a video with smaller duration?

EDIT: An example scenario:

> The thing I wanna do is to have 1 Frame for every minutes of streaming and I want to have, lets say `1 FPS` video with `1000 Frames`. In this scenario, the actual streaming duration becomes `1000 minutes`, but I want a 1 FPS video which has `1000 seconds` of duration.

Here is the code I am using below:

---

```
import os
import cv2 as cv
import math
cap = cv.VideoCapture('rtsp://**.***.**.*:*****/***********')

# Frame sizes
down_width = 640
down_height = 480
down_points = (down_width, down_height)

# stream fps and desired FPS
fpsSystem = cap.get(cv.CAP_PROP_FPS) # 25 in my case
fps = 1.0/60

# Frame Count parameters
frameRead       = 0             # successfully readed frame number
DesFrameCount =  60*6 # Desired frame count
takeFrameTime = 1/fps # every TakeFrameTime seconds frames will be stored
frameCycle      = 0             # every frameCycle. frame will be stored
frameWritten = 0

success = True
# Define the codec and create VideoWriter object
fourcc = cv.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'mp4v')

# Video Name
randomName = np.random.randint(0,1000)
out = cv.VideoWriter('output'+str(randomName) + ".mp4", fourcc, fps, (down_width,  down_height))

while success:

    success, frame = cap.read()

    if not success:
        print("Can't receive frame (stream end?). Exiting ...")
        break
    else:
        frameRead  += 1
        frameCycle += 1

    # Frame Resizing
    frame = cv.resize(frame,down_points,interpolation= cv.INTER_LINEAR)

    # Save the particular frame desired to be written according to frame parameters
    if frameCycle == math.floor(fpsSystem*takeFrameTime): 
        frameCycle    = 0
        out.write(frame)
        frameWritten += 1

    # Stop the loop when desired number of Frame obtained
    if cv.waitKey(1) == ord('q') or (frameWritten == DesFrameCount):
        break

# Release everything if job is finished
cap.release()
out.release()
cv.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: **fps** applies "frames per second". `fps = 1.0/60` applies `0.0167` frames per second (duration of each frame is going to be 60 seconds). For getting lower duration increase the fps (example: `fps = 60`). There may be other parts you have to change (I didn't try to follow the entire code).

Comment: @Rotem, thanks for replying. I will edit the question by adding an example scenario for making this clearer. For your reply, I want 1 FPS video output.

Comment: @Uce What happens if you set output FPS to be `1` then later write 60 times that same  frame in a For loop which uses `out.write(frame)`? Now do you have 1 image showing for  for 1 of minute? If yes, repeat for all other needed minutes (changing picture where needed).

Comment: @VC.One, hmm, in my code, it stores the same frame for every minute (`1 frame for 1 minute`) then it passes the second one and so on. In your advice, i think there will 60 times the same frames in every minutes (`60 frames for 1 minute, the same frames`), then the decimation might be a good choice (`M=60`) so that it can be had every `1:60` frames and duration might be decreased by 60?